# Any good articles about the SynchronizationContext, ExecutionContext or any other context?

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am learning the Task Parallel Library. And some context classes are mentioned from time to time. Such as SynchronizationContext, ExecutionContext. I am not sure if they are all the context is about.

I searched a lot about them, but with not so much gain. Though I think they shouldn't be that difficult to understand, but I am really kind of lost now.

So, could anyone share some good articles about:

- The design purpose of all these contexts.
- How to use them.

Thanks!

Comment: pfxteam blog.  For example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx

Comment: Please, please don't close this question.

Comment: And which are bad? I believe your question lacks concrete context. Citing @StephenCleary's [Another SynchronizationContext Gotcha: InvokeRequired?](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/09/another-synchronizationcontext-gotcha.html): "Given a SynchronizationContext of unknown type, you cannot tell if you are on a thread that is associated with that SynchronizationContext"

Answer (score 0):

From preface

> "**WARNING:** This post goes deep into an advanced area of .NET that most
>   developers never need to think about"

to:

- Stephen Toub. [ExecutionContext vs SynchronizationContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx)

I understood that (most) developers never need to think about ExecutionContext.

And  from

- [Stephen Toub. TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/09/22/9898090.aspx)

I understood that most of the mentioned above developers should abstract yourself from SynchronizationContexts intricacies and  worries by using TPL (Task Parallel Library, provided from .NET 4.0 on)  [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)